# How to keep text opacity 100 when its parent container is having opacity of 50

Tags: css, html, opacity

I have a list div which have a opacity set to 50 and inside this div I want to display some text with opacity 100,

Here's what I mean:

```
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
    Text
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS would be:

```
#outer {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#inner {
  opacity: 1.0;
}
```

I tried that, but it doesn't work.

please help

Regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS - Opaque text on low opacity div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401953/css-opaque-text-on-low-opacity-div)

Answer (score 23):

A simple and compatible solution is to remove all your `opacity`, and use:

```
#outer {
    background: url(50%-transparent-white.png);
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5)
}
```

- Browsers that support `rgba` will use the second `background` declaration with `rgba`.
- Browsers [that do not](http://caniuse.com/css3-colors) will ignore the second `background` declaration and use the `.png`.

<sub>The `.png` won't work in IE6, but that's [unlikely](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/81207/these-days-is-it-required-the-testing-for-a-desktop-website-for-ie6-and-ie7-or-i/81215#81215) to be a *problem*. If it is, [it can be resolved](http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_belatedPNG/).</sub>

---

Yet another method is detailed here:

http://robertnyman.com/2010/01/11/css-background-transparency-without-affecting-child-elements-through-rgba-and-filters/

Comment: Modern browsers can just use `background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5)`, no need for the `.png`.

Answer (score 13):

There's two ways to do this: One is to just set the background-color of the container to a transparent color,with `rgba(r,g,b,.5)`  - However, this is CSS3 and only supported in newer browsers.

The other way is to drop an absolutely positioned div inside the container, with an opacity of .5.

```
<div class="backgroundOpacity">
    My Epic Content
</div>
<br/>
<div class="backgroundDiv">
    <div id="background"> </div>
    My Other Epic Content
</div>
.backgroundOpacity {
 background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
.backgroundDiv {
  position:relative;  
}
#background {
 position:absolute;
  top:0;
   left:0;
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   background-color:#000;
   opacity: .5; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/thomas4g/vVt8D/1/

Answer (score 7):

```
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
```

Answer (score 4):

You could set your outer div like this

`background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  opacity: inherit;`

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by a trick and it's is so easy, here is how:

you wanna take the text outside of the transparent div and that's by making another div sat as position: relative;

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to contribute an answer. It’s because of helpful peers like yourself that we’re able to learn together as a community. Here are a few tips on how to make your answer great: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).