# Animate button background with Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, fade

I am trying to fade-in a background image on a button on `mouseover` (and fade it out on `mouseout`), without the actual button text fading.

```
$('btn').hover(function () {
    $('btn', this).stop().animate({
        "opacity": 1
    });
}, function () {
    $('btn', this).stop().animate({
        "opacity": 0
    });
});
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/craigzilla/fFq2A

Comment: Your selector is wrong `'btn'` should be `'.btn'`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.btn').hover(function () {
    $(this).animate({
        "opacity": 0
    });
}, function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        "opacity": 1
    });
});
```

Your selector is wrong `'btn'` should be `'.btn'` and `$('btn', this)` should be `$(this)`.

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fFq2A/3/).

Comment: Is there any way to just affect the background and NOT the text?

Comment: No, `opacity` always affect the element and its children. The normal approach to solve this problem is to use absolute positioning of elements. You can read some solutions in the following links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10021302/how-to-apply-an-opacity-without-affecting-a-child-element-with-html-css / http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-opacity-that-doesnt-affect-child-elements/ / http://robertnyman.com/2010/01/11/css-background-transparency-without-affecting-child-elements-through-rgba-and-filters/

Answer (score 1):

You have assigned div as button as well as background.so if you try to fadein/fadeout background,it'll fade in fade out both button and background....

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fFq2A/4/)**

Here's the code:

```
$('.btn').hover(function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": 0});
}, function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": 1});
});
```