# How do I change the opacity of a background image without affecting child elements?

Tags: html, css, background, opacity

I am trying to make the background image at 70% opacity without affecting the text in front of it (within the same div).

---

HTML

```css
#home {
  opacity: 0.7;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url("...");
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div .welcome {
  background-size: cover;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: black;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="home" class="section">
            <p class="welcome"><strong>Hello,<br>My name is Sean</strong></p>
          </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply an opacity without affecting a child element with html/css?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10021302/how-to-apply-an-opacity-without-affecting-a-child-element-with-html-css)

Comment: Or alternatively [CSS background-image-opacity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890218/css-background-image-opacity)

Answer (score 1):

By using a pseudo element and `position:absolute`

*Do note that element that is a direct child of the `home` will need a position, like I set to the `content`, or you need to set `z-index: -1` on the pseudo element, and if not, the pseudo will be layered on top*

```css
body {
  background: blue
}
#home {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#home::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/200/f00);  /*  image is red but blue shine 
                                                           through so becomes purple */
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="home">

  <div class="content">
    
    Content not affected
    
  </div>
  
</div>
```