# How to make a tooltip have an opacity of 1 when the element it's in is set to a lower value on hover

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I set up my `a` elements to have `opacity: 0.6` when they are hovered, yet this also affects my tooltips and fades them.

I am using Bootstrap 4.

I have tried the following with/without `data-`, `:hover` and `>`.

1. `img[data-toggle=tooltip]:hover .tooltip { opacity: 1 }`
2. `a *[data-toggle=tooltip] .tooltip { opacity: 1 }`
3. `a:hover > img[data-toggle=tooltip] > .tooltip { opacity: 1 }`

Here is the style that it's conflicting with (which is before the styles above, so it should be applied:

```
a:hover {
  color: red;
  opacity: 0.6;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:focus {
  color: red;
  opacity: 0.3;
  outline: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

And this is how I have it set up in my HTML:

```
<a href="#">
  <img class="card botdrop foot-brand" data-toggle="tooltip"
                                       data-placement="top"
                                       data-title="Twitter" 
                                       src="picture.png"
                                       data-original-title=""
                                       title="">
</a>
```

How can I make it so the tooltip is fully opaque when it appears and not `opacity: 0.6`?

Answer (score 0):

Since the tool tip is a child of the `a` element it will 'inherit' this property.

This solution may help you: [How to apply an opacity without affecting a child element with html/css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10021302/how-to-apply-an-opacity-without-affecting-a-child-element-with-html-css)