# Is it possible to prevent the opacity of HTML elements from affecting the opacity of the TAB helpers?

Tags: html, css, browser, accessibility, opacity

(I wrote "tab helpers" in the title, which I guess is an invented terminology. Please, correct me.)

In the snippet below there's two checkboxes, one of which has opacity reduced to 20%.

```css
.checkbox1 {
  opacity: 100%;
}
.checkbox2 {
  opacity: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkbox1">
  <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck1">
</div>
<div class="checkbox2">
  <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck2">
</div>
```

If I tab-select the second one, I see this (well, not the stuff in blue):

[image]

Is there anyway to have that yellow thing retain 100% opacity even if the element's opacity is set via CSS to other than 100%?

I guess this might be all up to the browser, but I'm really not sure.

Comment: Your code does not show a yellow border on the checkbox. Could you put up a snippet which shows it - I can't guess where it is coming from.

Comment: why are you applying opacity to start with?

Answer (score 0):

The yellow stroke is the `outline` and [is notoriously hard to style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457849/how-to-remove-the-border-highlight-on-an-input-text-element) since you're correct that it is browser-specific. User-defined styles can and often are disregarded wholesale by the browser.

As part of the element, it is affected by the value of the element's `opacity` property. This means you cannot set its `opacity` directly.

If you want to make the element semi-transparent without affecting the `outline`, you should style the other parts of the element with `RGBA` colors so you can set the transparency per-part. (see: [I do not want to inherit the child opacity from the parent in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770341/i-do-not-want-to-inherit-the-child-opacity-from-the-parent-in-css) or [@Rohit Azad Malik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1365428/rohit-azad-malik)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10022927/14956277) to [How to apply an opacity without affecting a child element with html/css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10021302/how-to-apply-an-opacity-without-affecting-a-child-element-with-html-css?rq=1)).

There are ways to [style a `checkbox`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-a-checkbox-using-css) (or other `input` types), but they're browser-specific.