# How do I make a div transparent on a white body background?

Tags: css, transparent

The background-color of my body is #ffffff.  And I have a div that I need is colored but it needs to be transparent or see through.  Is it possible to do this using CSS3 or do I have to use images to achieve this?

```
body {
background-color: #ffffff;
}
.box {
background-color: #999999;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #999999 0%, #444444 100%) !important;
opacity: 0.7;
}
```

Update:

If you go here: http://pinesframework.org/pnotify/#demos-simple and look for the demo for Transparent Success you can see how the pop-up looks see through on a white background.  I need to do something like that without using an image as they are using one.

Comment: you would use CSS3 if you want it animated to transparent...I'm confused as to what you want?

Comment: @ryansaxe the div doesn't appear transparent because the background is white.  If the background color is different it would look better.  So I am confused as to how to approach this..

Comment: So didn't you just answer your own question? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If you go here: http://pinesframework.org/pnotify/#demos-simple and look for the demo for Transparent Success you can see how the pop-up looks see through on a white background.  I need to do something like that without using an image as they are using one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS - Opaque text on low opacity div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401953/css-opaque-text-on-low-opacity-div)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED:** Per your comment below, this question appears to be a duplicate of [CSS - Opaque text on low opacity div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401953/css-opaque-text-on-low-opacity-div).

You need to change the opacity of the background instead of the element:

```
.box {
    rgba(255,0,0,0.6);
}
```

Or, since you are using a gradient, I would use this:

[Ultimate CSS Gradient Generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

It will allow you to do semi-transparent backgrounds with a gradient.

Comment: Thanks.  But it also shouldn't apply to the text.  If you go here: http://pinesframework.org/pnotify/#demos-simple and look at the demo for Transparent Success you can see what I am trying to do.  I want the similar transparent image that looks transparent on a white background.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want an alpha transparent background color. If that's the case, you can use RGBA colors, rather than a solid hex value and an `opacity` property. This way, only the background will have transparency, not the content.

In your case it would be:

```
.box {
    background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.7);    
}
```

You can also specify a fallback color to browsers that don't support RGBA (IE 8 and older), or create a PNG image with the color fill you want. My vote is toward progressive enhancement, and just specify an alternate color for browsers that don't understand RGBA:

```
.box {
    background-color: #ff4c4c;
    background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.7);    
}
```